# Defining a generic TypeScript type with argument injection

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

I am trying to describe a missing property in TypeScript generics. I wrote a curried example function `example` that receives two arguments. The first argument is a result producer function `f` that is able to produce the wanted result. The second argument is an argument object `a` that contains all needed arguments except one. The missing property `bar` needs to be added into the argument object before it an be used to compute the result. However, no matter what way I write the type signature, I always get a type error when attempting to construct the complete argument object.

```js
type Example = <A extends { bar: string }, R>(
  f: (a: A & { bar: string }) => R,
) => (a: Omit<A, 'bar'>) => R;

const example: Example = (f) => (a) => f({ ...a, bar: 'bar' });
```

The errors I keep getting seem to indicate that the result function `f` might not accept an arbitrary string and might have special requirements for the string it receives as the injected `bar` argument. I wish to strip the result function `f` from the priviledge of being able to define arbitrary extensions to the string. I want to assert that the result function `f` needs to deal with any string it is given. However, I don't mind the result function `f` defining arbitrary extensions for other parts of the argument object.

Comment: Well, the input to `f` should be `Omit<A, 'bar'> & {bar: string}` in order for your implementation of `example` to work, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLyMeW).  If that meets your needs I could write up an answer; if not, please [edit] the example code to show a use case it doesn't work for (presumably something about *calling* `example`, which is not shown in your question).

Comment: I think `Omit<A, 'bar'> & {bar: string}` is the solution I was looking for, thank you! I think I had the correct solution already written out for a moment but some double omit bug in my utilities prevented me from realising. I encountered some errors like `Omit<Omit<A,'bar'>,'bar'>` is not assignable to `Omit<A, 'bar'>`. Seems like the amount of times properties are omited is significant when checking assignability.

Comment: Even adding `Omit<A, 'bar'>` solves `const example: Example = (f) => (a) => f({ ...a, bar: 'bar' })` it will not help because when you try use `example` you will get error: `const q = example((p: { foo: 1, bar: 'bar'}) => 2); // Error` [play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDbQLxQDwEEoRzAQB2AJgM5QDeUARggE4BcUFwjAliQOZQC+AGigAlAHwAKAFBQoAM1YSErAPJJOwPMIDkDRtrFQAZDXpNW7LrwEBKKBkMjBUuw6hLV6zbh16DrxwBuKSkAYwB7EnYCRBR0VnhkNEx3OQD3BHS5CVoAOnyEYT1WXSZtW2CwyOiAR3sYpPQJCTBWWjlw8NYARiLzKFL9fnSAJhtAoA)

Comment: @AndreiKovalev I actually wanted to disallow functions that depend on a specific kind of string `example((p: { foo: 1, bar: 'bar'}) => 2)` and only accept functions that accept *any* `string` as `bar`. However, passing that kind of function `example((p: { foo: 1, bar: string }) => 2)` does not work either. Passing type arguments explicitly `example<{ foo: 1 }, number>((p: { foo: 1, bar: string }) => 2)` solves the problem but is ofcourse a bit cumbersome. I am still in the middle of exploring the full answer you posted. Perhaps it solves the type inference problem.

Comment: I updated my answer regarding your use case. Please check this out.

Comment: Thank you all! I incorporated some of the learnings from this thread into a type signature improvement proposal for Middy middleware engine. Here is a link to the issue https://github.com/middyjs/middy/issues/914

Answer (score 2):

The error message at `f({ ...a, bar: 'bar' })` says

```
/* Argument of type 'Omit<A, "bar"> & { bar: string; }' is not 
assignable to parameter of type 'A & { bar: string; }'. */
```

because the value `{ ...a, bar: "bar" }` is inferred to be `Omit<A, "bar"> & { bar: string }`, but you've got the `f()` function annotated that it takes a value of type `A & { bar: string }`.  The compiler cannot be sure that those types are the same (and won't be the same if `A` has a `bar` property narrower than `string`), so it complains.

That error message implies that everything would be fine if `f()` accepted `Omit<A, "bar"> & { bar: string }` instead.  Indeed, if you make that change, it compiles without error:

```
type Example = <A extends { bar: string }, R>(
  f: (a: Omit<A, 'bar'> & { bar: string }) => R,
) => (a: Omit<A, 'bar'>) => R;
const example: Example = (f) => (a) => f({ ...a, bar: 'bar' });  // okay
```

That might be good enough for you, but there are a few more changes I'd make here.  The type of `{ ...a, bar: 'bar' }` would be `Omit<A, "bar"> & { bar: string }` even if `a` were of type `A`, because that's what spreading with [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) does in TypeScript.  Presumably this is what you thought `a` was in the first place, and only put `Omit` there to fix things.  So let's eliminate that:

```
  type Example = <A extends { bar: string }, R>(
    f: (a: Omit<A, 'bar'> & { bar: string }) => R,
  ) => (a: A) => R;
  const example: Example = (f) => (a) => f({ ...a, bar: 'bar' });  // okay
```

And finally, there's no reason why `A` *must* have a `bar` property of type `string`.  Even if `A` has no `bar` property, or an incompatible `bar` property, the function should still behave as desired (since `{ ...a, bar: 'bar' }` will overwrite any `bar` property on `A`, or provide one if `A` doesn't have one).  So we can remove the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on `A`:

```
type Example = <A, R>(
  f: (a: Omit<A, 'bar'> & { bar: string }) => R,
) => (a: A) => R;
const example: Example = (f) => (a) => f({ ...a, bar: 'bar' });  // okay
```

---

The only issue I see now is that it will be hard for the compiler to infer `A` properly by a call to `example`:

```
const exampled = example((x: { baz: number, bar: string }) =>
  x.baz.toFixed(2) + x.bar.toUpperCase()
); // error! A is inferred as unknown, and so
// Argument of type '(x: { baz: number; bar: string;}) => string' is not
// assignable to parameter of type '(a: Omit<unknown, "bar"> 
// & { bar: string; }) => string'.
```

The compiler just can't infer `A` from a value of type `Omit<A, "bar"> & { bar: string }`, and I can't seem to rephrase that type in a way that works.

You can, of course, manually specify `A` (and also `R`, because there's no *partial* type argument inference as requested in [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242), at least not as of TS4.8):

```
const exampled = example<{ baz: number }, string>(
  x => x.baz.toFixed(2) + x.bar.toUpperCase()
); // okay
// const exampled: (a: {  baz: number; }) => string
```

And verify that it works as expected:

```
console.log(exampled({ baz: Math.PI })) // "3.14BAR"
```

So that's, I guess, the answer to the question as asked.

---

The issue of inference here seems to be out of scope. If you want inference to work for callers, you pretty much need to do something like this:

```
type Example = <A, R>(
  f: (a: A) => R,
) => (a: Omit<A, "bar">) => R;

const example: Example = (f) => (a) => f({ ...a, bar: 'bar' } as
  Parameters<typeof f>[0]);  // okay

const exampled = example((x: { baz: number, bar: string }) =>
  x.baz.toFixed(2) + x.bar.toUpperCase()
); // okay
/* const exampled: (a: Omit<{  baz: number; bar: string; }, "bar">) => string

console.log(exampled({ baz: Math.PI })) // "3.14BAR"
```

So we're sacrificing some type safety in the implementation of `example` (using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to claim that the argument to `f` is the right type, which is technically not 100% safe but fine in practice) to get nice behavior for those who call it.  It's possible that *this* is the way you want to proceed, depending on whether you're going to *implement* `Example`s or *call* them more often.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPkkqJLAsgEIBOA9gNYTB5HFIAuAnjMgKIAe4GBmQBeJAB4Agkgj92TACZQ8SAEYhqALiRR21AJbAA5kgC+AGiQAlAHwAKVmyQAzHfZA6ZAMlUbtuvpGpmYAlEiitjYWTkjhkUgeOgDyYAbs0lYA5P5ZtvFR1gDchM7wtMB6soJgwhA6AkIiEYkuBYkg7S72uEgAdAMgVv46OZpZ5qElxGalJODQcIhIAGIG-ACMLM5cPEiNtc3i0tUKwMp+mjp6hibmVnaOzsRuHSlpGVLZuVG+vSOBW4hdrWGLOdpJJCpdKZJBjah5EHTNjlSrsapNer7Gp1Fr2NoRKIeLo9fqDYZXOG5SZFYgAejpSAYIE4rFmrFIiwoq3WACYWLFdnwcUdJDI5GcLv9KTdgvcbA5Yi93J4oR9YfC8kg-uoZUE7mFCdFYhDVVIkbFUVU5JiGiKxK1TSTegM+kNdQFNTT6YzmayZoQOQtyMs1vwAMzbNhC7GYlqwx5K1wq94wr5U8a-S4BWUGkFgtimrwWsoVa32u1x8T4p1G7ou8ke0bUsK0pAMpn0FlzYg2w4Qez2fg6aVYHTAACuYDUEGoFJz+uBhKT-D6GiwfXYtDDEEU9l54QA1EhV-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)

Comment: Thank you! Well explained! I just started to look at the type inference issue. It is nice that you covered that as well. The `Omit<a, 'bar'>` type of the second argument in my original code example was required to explain why you can't just do a direct call `f(a)` on the result function. After the fixes you propose it is no longer necessary because the received argument object `a` would no longer fulfil the argument type of the result function `f` without addition of the missing property `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the parameter type `A extends { bar: string }` could be instantiated for example by type `{ bar: 'not bar' }`. If it is then trying to pass the argument `{ ...a, bar: 'bar' }` the function `f` will throw an error. To illustrate this this is an example:

```
type E = typeof a<{ bar: 'not bar' }, unknown>

const example1: E = (f) => (a) => f({ ...a, bar: 'bar' })
// The expected type comes from property 'bar'
// which is declared here on type '{ bar: "not bar"; }'

const example2: E = (f) => (a) => f({ ...a, bar: 'not bar' }) // Ok
```

This will work for you:

```
type Example1 = <F extends (a: any) => R, R>(
    f: F & ((a: Parameters<F>[0]) => R),
) => (a: Omit<Parameters<F>[0], 'bar'>) => R;

const example3: Example1 = (f) => (a) => f({ ...a, bar: 'bar' }); // Ok

const q1 = example3((p: {a: 3, bar: 'b'}) => 3)
// q1: (a: Omit<{
//      a: 3;
//      bar: 'b';
// }, "bar">) => number

const a1 = q1({ a: 3 }) // number
const a2 = q1({ a: 4 }) // Error: Type '4' is not assignable to type '3'
const a3 = q1({ a: 3, foo: 1 }) // Error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=31&ssc=41&pln=17&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDbQLxQDwEEoRzAQB2AJgM5QDeUARggE4BcUFwjAliQOZQC+AGigAlAHwAKALAAoKPKgAzVhIStcASigYxowbK06oq1gHkknYHmEByBoxtjDukQG5ZsgMYB7EuwKIKOis8MhomMaKzsYI0YoStAB0yQjC9qx2TDYCGu4ysmQQnqhM0D5+wFBqsIHhHjKgkLDaUI0Q3opV2LTpUDYk3pX22UJQAK4kANYDAO4kYvXl-oRh6ACMIS0SUdq6qnEJUMmJqfRMGcM5sgD011AAKgAW0ISQnsRkreBl3kgQVIpGL8oGAgZBGKA+sMbncZo9OJ5HlBOFRCsVSp9noxoL4vk0bD1zlAAEQDIZMYmuAQ2Ra+Za1dAAJk2WG20X2uyUh2Op16-UGZwcOSgtygpkm9TaNVWEDWLWwADEAsRyFQTFUSCBoiJhOJpHIFMooEqAGTGdUABSYyAgxEYFEVYgA2gAGAC62o0+hk7Oq5ks2CtjBtdodCud7tswycnLctIqARlAGYQgzZVsdkYOUZ4kkUmkiZkhfxciK7uL4-4AI5yrArIIQJMSCRgVjUapJgssKE2EucpMaGFQGsqP0WKzUIcKeQdvKi6eCi42Od3UbE+zEmNGEhjJB0CCMSuVBC14drQ4d4Wind7g9eOnHxktGsX1gAFivdxgjCB3fu3z6N9shRKAySqCgKE4HgSAQOh0Fabw8WgGwkxpGQlmPJNn3PWgO2ERRvG8Vg5T7UVv1-WQgA)

And if you need that `f` function has a mandatory type of argument which assigns to `{ bar: string }` this is an enhancement:

```
type Example = <F extends (a: any) => R, R>(
  f: F &
    ((a: Parameters<F>[0]) => R) &
    (Parameters<F>[0] extends { bar: string } ? unknown : never)
) => (a: Omit<Parameters<F>[0], "bar">) => R;

const example: Example = (f) => (a) => f({ ...a, bar: "bar" }); // Ok

const q1 = example((p: { a: 3; bar: "b" }) => 3);
// q1: (a: Omit<{
//      a: 3;
//      bar: 'b';
// }, "bar">) => number

const q2 = example((p: { a: 3; foo: "b" }) => 3); // Error

const a1 = q1({ a: 3 }); // number
const a2 = q1({ a: 4 }); // Error: Type '4' is not assignable to type '3'
const a3 = q1({ a: 3, foo: 1 }); // Error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=42&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDbQLxQDwDEoRzAQB2AJgM5QAUCAXFAiSAJRQYB8UASgDQ8dqAKChQAZg3wAyEaJq0GABQQAnZBGIqKeDgG0ADAF02nHmxlyaytUg0QtOg4YJFSlKAG8oAI1UMKwCoAliQA5lAAvlAA-FAAriQA1iQA9gDuJFAMJBAAbvYsQiZcClAA8khBwNjW6prauHpG-ABEviotHMU8ANxCQgDGKSQBLshoEAzw4+jsNGLdtN1i1F4AdBsI-O0MbaotkSw9UAD0J+WJ-UMjwFAAjgCMc4QzENTUYAxe9FAAzMc7KBtA4Rbq-I5CM73B4MUoVKrYDyQ86WRgMf7I1E+PxQADk3lxfShEVa7U63RIcSQ3nsV2GozuACZnogUOh3p9PGi-scxCkUrtvCCwUdTucYCoVCkVHSbownlhHqtub9DscoZTqbTrqMEMzFQ9lT8ACxqsWwSXShgAFXA0FxxtxUCCVFStwQFAoQVCJAQ3lmwBSUFAkDxv1xg3p7tVBqN6P4fIFUCeoPV4stMqAA)

This is an enhancement for the case when the function `f` must be disallowed if it depends on a specific kind of string (as I learned from the recent reply it is a requirement):

```
type Example = <F extends (a: any) => R, R, P = Parameters<F>[0]>(
  f: F &
    ((a: P) => R) &
    ("bar" extends keyof P ? unknown : never) &
    ({ bar: string } extends Pick<P, "bar" & keyof P> ? unknown : never)
) => (a: Omit<P, "bar">) => R;

const example: Example = (f) => (a) => f({ ...a, bar: "bar" }); // Ok

const q1 = example((p: { a: 3; bar: string }) => 3);
// q1: (a: Omit<{
//      a: 3;
//      bar: 'b';
// }, "bar">) => number

const q2 = example((p: { a: 3; bar: "b" }) => 3); // Error
const q3 = example((p: { a: 3 }) => 3); // Error
const q4 = example((p: { a: 3; foo: string }) => 3); // Error

const a1 = q1({ a: 3 }); // number
const a2 = q1({ a: 4 }); // Error: Type '4' is not assignable to type '3'
const a3 = q1({ a: 3, foo: 1 }); // Error
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDbQLxQDwDEoRzAQB2AJgM5QAUCAXFAiSAJRQYB8UASgDQ-8ACuyiCEAJ2QRi4ing4BtAAwBdDtQBQUKADMG+AGRbtNWg0FtOPNkZM0ARACMJ9gkVKUoAawggA9jqiUAD8UACuJF4kfgDuJFAMJBAAbhDiNsba1ADeUM7iDBTA4gCWJADmUAC+bsTkVIIlAMZe2IL8Ti5QBt6+AaJcoRFRsfGJKWksGpZcZlAA8kglwG0d+fYcMzwA3BoaTX4kRW7IaBAM8KfoItQ6W7RbOjlQAHRvCPz5DJ3irlUs2ygAHogQsvHsDkdgFAAI4ARhEhCuEGo1DADFy9CgAGZAV8oEVShVqltsQCNCDYXCGHNFstsNkKaC7IwGLimSy8hIGAByRw83aUqprFybdhcEhhJCONIQw7HGEAJkRiBQ6FR6KgmLZeO5UCcf1JAOBoJg4nEfnE+3l0Jh2JVyI1GNZOJJ4pxxspZotVshCoALA61Si0c6sbjdH4-IVimVKv93WTAV7zZa5VDGAisPDnuGScnQZLpbK-dCEMrs3DcwxA-8C7BUwUoAAVcDQHn+nlQEpUaJligUErlEgIRzXYB+KCgSBQHnYnnWjMIe2V6s4-g6KMMBF1k0Nn0aIA)

Comment: I have now studied this example quite a bit. It has some nice features. However, it fails to detect errors within the implementation. For example `const example2: Example = (f) => (a) => f({ bar: "bar" });` passes the type check despite not doing the spread `...a` at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, TypeScript can't control the implementations for generic functions. It is much as assuming.

Comment: I mean it can control on some level but it is limited by design.

Comment: I think your solution would be better if you got rid of the `any` by doing `F extends (a: P) => R`, and then added an explicit type cast to the call `f({ ...a, bar: "bar" } as any)`. An explicit type cast would make the dangerous spot more obvious.

Comment: Sure. In a real codebase, I would not go with such a grade of complicity. I see it here as just a puzzle to solve. It allows me to achieve better fluency in TypeScript to be able to make real tasks easier. I am glad you found some features in my solution helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is what `as` is for, it complains `'A' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{ bar: string; }'` but given you're cloning the properties à la `{...a, bar:'bar'}` you *know* it'll match type `A`; all you're trying to do is enforce type-checking to code using the resultant function. So long as you're sure of what you're doing in your `example()` middleware (e.g. `A` isn't an instantiated `class` object or something where you'll need to do a little more than just enumerate properties) there's no need to make the compiler 110% happy.

```
const barFunc = ({foo, bar} :{foo :string, bar :string}) => (
    `${foo} ${bar}`
);


function example<
    A extends {bar :string},
    R
>(
    f :(a :A) => R
) {
    return (a :Omit<A, 'bar'>|A) => (
        f({...a, bar:'bar'} as A)
    );
}

const test = example(barFunc);
console.log(test({foo:'missing'}));
console.log(test({foo:'overwritten', bar:'ignored'})); //I added `|A` to the typing just in case you're going to be feeding existing calls to f() instead now to your middleware
```

Basically it's complaining "hey, what if 'A' isn't `{bar :string; [others :string] :unknown;}` but actually `class { bar :string; memberFunction() { return this.bar; } }` for this `f`?". If you're sure it's a basic object, `{...a}` is fine, and `as` just lets the compiler know you know what you're doing, but *everyone calling `example()` needs to be aware of this* (which is fine if it's just you and `example` is a non-exported function in a module of yours).

Honestly, if you're not using this to blanket-override a bunch of different functions you should just tailor-wrap them so the compiler just knows what's going on and doesn't need any hints in the first place.

```
const barFunc = ({foo, bar} :{foo :string, bar :string}) => (
    `${foo} ${bar}`
);

type A = Parameters<typeof barFunc>[0];
function test(obj :Omit<A, 'bar'>|A) {
    return barFunc({...obj, bar:'bar'});
}

console.log(test({foo:'missing'}));
console.log(test({foo:'overwritten', bar:'ignored'})); //I added `|A` to the typing just in case you're going to be feeding existing calls to f() instead now to your middleware
```

Comment: I would happily do the cast if I was working on hidden code and was in a hurry, and the resulting code would be far from the worst code people write to meet deadlines. However, I was wondering how to do it without casts for a public library. Perhaps I should have added the cast in my code example. I could then have formated my question around how to eliminate the cast from the example. Even so, I do think casts are fine when the type inferrer clearly does not understand what is happening. Though I feel, in this particular case, the type inferrer is probably on to something.

Comment: Yeah @cyberixae that's what I was getting at in the second part of the answer. The compiler is 'on to' the fact that `{...a, bar:''}` doesn't satisfy all possible types that `f` might be accepting; imagine if `A` was a class object with a member function (id est, using `this`). If `f` makes a call to that function after your rest clone it would error, so typescript is right to say your implementation wont ever fully match the typing. You must cast or do something much more complicated; the typing isn't your issue.

Comment: Remember how the second example compiles without the cast? That's because TS knows the objects are not classes. [But what if they were?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCD2AjaBvAUNT1FgE7QC4IAXXASwDsBzAbgy2HgpNwFdhj5cAKHfI0pSoBKVPSxZiACzIQAdH2gBebHjoSAvuOjaAZvHjdR6CRNwBTYq1wVo02QrXatWtI2bFVuAGKsKwZWheJEIERFElAD4g7QADABIURCQ5fUNhDWhE5MRHXA1YtGE6NGIATwAHc2gAQUCABTwwAFtLc1wIAB5yqvhdL19-SIBtAAYAXTpdPw4yJjtzEm4kACtCAHlmsmJOmoAaaAByPkPIgB8a420LKxsBme4UOWfVg74CY7xDjWK0LSA)